# Find Executables that link an SO file

Tags: find, links, shared-libraries

I know that I can print out the so files that an exe has linked with ldd. What I want is to go the other way.

My current approach is to run something like `find / -type f -executable -exec ldd {} \; | grep my_lib.so` however that takes a very long time to run (expectantly) since it has to search through everything. Is there a fast way or command to find which exes point at an so in linux?

Answer (score 0):

If you use some Linux distribution, there should be - but only for packages in distribution, for all stuff installed via some other way (like in `/opt` or `/usr/local`) you would still need to use your original method.

for example, on Debian-based distro, we would first find in which package is our shared library:

```
# dpkg -S /usr/lib/libgs.so.9.05
libgs9: /usr/lib/libgs.so.9.05
```

and then find all packages which use that library (and keep copy in file **packages.txt**):

```
# dpkg-query -W -f='${binary:Package} ${Depends}\n' | grep -w libgs9 | awk '{print $1}' | tee packages.txt
ghostscript
gimp
libgs9
libgs9-common
```

If you need to know exact binaries which use the libraries, you could parse that output some more:

```
# while read pkg; do dpkg -L $pkg | xargs -i sh -c 'test -f {} -a -x {} && ldd {} | fgrep -H --label={}  libgs.so.9'; done < packages.txt
/usr/bin/gs:    libgs.so.9 => /usr/lib/libgs.so.9 (0x00007fefe5611000)
/usr/bin/ghostscript:   libgs.so.9 => /usr/lib/libgs.so.9 (0x00007fbad0d71000)
/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/file-ps:     libgs.so.9 => /usr/lib/libgs.so.9 (0x00007f75f0a51000)
```